# Linear combination false / true

Tags: linear-algebra

I got 3 sayings I was unsure why they are false / true

the equation is: A*x=b

1. if Vector B is Linear combination of RowA vectors then the set has **at least** a single solution ( false )
2. the set has at least a single solution if vector b is Linear combination of ColumnA vectors (answer seems to be true)
3. if ColumnA and b vector are a linear dependent group there for the set has **at least** a single solution

Comment: $Ax=b$ is not a set, it is an equation.

Comment: Which ones do you think are true and which ones are not true?

Comment: I am not sure honestly, sadly I dont "see" the connection between the rows / columns to the solution

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is that when you multiply a matrix $A$ and a column vector $x$, you get a column vector which is a linear combination of the columns of $A$. For example, suppose
$$
A = \pmatrix{
3 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -3 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 5 \\
}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
x = \pmatrix{
7 \\ 4 \\ -2
}.
$$
When I multiply these together, I'm taking a linear combination of the columns of $A$, and the coefficients in this linear combination come from $x$. More specifically, $Ax$ will be $7$ times the *first* column of $A$ (since the first element of $x$ is $7$) plus $4$ times the *second* column of $A$ plus $-2$ times the *third* column of $A$:
$$
\pmatrix{
3 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -3 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 5 \\
}
\pmatrix{
7 \\ 4 \\ -2
} = 
7 \pmatrix{
3 \\ 0 \\ 1
}
\,+\, 4 \pmatrix{
0 \\ -3 \\ 1
}
\,+\, (-2) \pmatrix{
-1 \\ 2 \\ 5
}.
$$
This is the connection between solutions to $Ax = b$ and columns of $A$ that will allow you to answer your questions.

Comment: What a great explanation! thank you very much for that
Is there a connection between b and the row vectors ?

Comment: There isn't a direct connection between $Ax$ and the rows of $A$. However, if you take $yA$, where $y$ is a row vector (note the matrix is on the right now), then you get a linear combination of the *rows* of $A$.